# Сортировка массива php по ключу

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Есть **игроки** и их **очки**.
Задача отсортировать игроков по очкам.

```
class player{  
var $name; 
var $pts; 
};

$maks = new player;
$maks->name = "Макс";
$maks->pts = -20;

$dima = new player;
$dima->name = "Дима";
$dima->pts = -10;

$kost = new player;
$kost->name = "Костя";
$kost->pts = 23;

$stas = new player;
$stas->name = "Стас";
$stas->pts = -120;

$jenia = new player;
$jenia->name = "Женя";
$jenia->pts = 20;

$den = new player;
$den->name = "Денис";
$den->pts = 10;

$place = array($stas,$kost,$den,$maks,$jenia,$dima);
```

Нужно отсортировать этот массив так, чтобы он пришел к такому виду:

```
$place = array($kost,$jenia,$den,$maks,$dima,$stas);
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Используй функцию [usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php), навскидку:

```
usort ($place, function($a, $b) { 
    return ($a->pts < $b->pts) ? -1 : 1;
} );
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/u212811432/public_html/gpt-site_re/index.php on line 190

Comment: исправил пример